# questions on Linux command "find -exec {}"

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to update a file in subversion. I need to add a line in makefile, in order to build up the revised version of code. Here is the command I tried to find the place in make file.

> find . -name "*ake*" -exec grep filename {}  /dev/null \;

It works. But my questions are: 
 1. What is the "\;" for? If I change it, there will be error message.

2 The /dev/null didn't change the results. I know this is the device where dispose all the "garbage information". But I still don't quite understand it in this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure /dev/null has a role here - this should expand into simply 'grep filename {current_file_path}'  The /dev/null should not be required.

Comment: That `/dev/null` puzzles me. Perhaps the creator thought `find` worked as globbing, and `exec` would be run whether `find` found anything or didn't, providing `grep` with at least 1 file to search in? Any way, I see zero reason for it to be there.

Comment: `find ... -exec grep -e filename /dev/null {} +` would be considerably more efficient, by the way; the `\;` variant doesn't really make sense in this use case.

Comment: @Wrikken, some versions of `grep` behave differently with exactly 1 input file than with two-or-more. The `/dev/null` ensures that the two-or-more case is always the one in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\;` indicates the end of the command to be executed by `find`. The `\` is required to stop the shell interpreting the `;` itself. From `man find`:

```
-exec command ;
          Execute  command;  true  if  0 status is returned.  All following 
          arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an 
          argument consisting of ‘;’ is encountered.
```

The `/dev/null` is a clever trick that took me a while to figure out. If grep is passed more than one filename it prints the containing filename before each match. `/dev/null` acts as an empty file containing no matches, but makes grep think it is always passed more then one filename. A much clearer alternative suggested by richard would be to use grep's `-H` option:

```
       -H, --with-filename
              Print the filename for each match. This is the default when there 
              is more than one file to search.
```

Comment: So could use `grep -H'

Comment: Yes, in fact I would say that would be a more clear and therefore better approach.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `-exec command {} +` is another POSIX-standardized usage, completely valid when the command is `grep`, and also considerably more efficient compared to running a grep command per result.

Comment: I got it. It's like "grep -H" vs "grep -h"